# How does the .join function work with a for loop?

Tags: python

I have come across this line of code, but I am unsure of what it means.

```
print(' '.join(str(j) for j in arr))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.join` joins all elements of an iterable with the string. In this case the empty space.

`str(j) for j in arr` is a generator expression that produces an iterable that is the stringified-version of every element in `arr`.

Answer (score 1):

The `str.join()` method will take in an iterable, and return a string.
The string will consist of all the strings inside the iterable, connected with the specified string.

So

```
' '.join(['hello','world'])
```

will return

```
'hello world'
```

The `' '.join(str(j) for j in arr)` you see is almost like simply doing `' '.join(arr)`,
but since the elements inside `arr` aren't strings, the generator `str(j) for j in arr`
is used to convert each element into a string.

Answer (score 1):

The line `(str(j) for j in arr)` is a generator expression:
You can then use `.join()` to iterate over the yielded elements that output from the generator expression. For example:

```
    ### say arr is a list of numbers
    >>> print(''.join(str(j) for j in [6,7,8]))
    ... 678
```

Generator expressions are *iterable* and when you make use of the `.join()` it helps to concatenate and join the individual elements.